# Remove directory name from php array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, getfiles, filelist

In CodeIgnitor i am getting this array using directory_map.

```
Array
(
    [0] => preview.zip
    [1] => RealEsta - Email Marketing Template.zip
    [2] => thumbnail
    [3] => thumbnail.jpg
)
```

I want to remove directory name from array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => preview.zip
    [1] => RealEsta - Email Marketing Template.zip
    [2] => thumbnail.jpg
)
```

like this. How i will remove this directory from this file list array.

Comment: And how do you want to know that index 2 is a directory?

Comment: It would help to see how you created the array in the first place, because many methods for directory listing in PHP have native ways to exclude dirs or limit to files only.

Comment: According to the docs, subdirectories are themselves arrays, so you can filter them by `is_array()`. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html  But that implies numeric-indexed elements are _not_ directories, so `thumbnail` might actually be _file_ without an extension.

Comment: `$map = directory_map('./uploads/'.$user_id.'/files', TRUE, FALSE);
print_r($map);`

this is my code which return above array how i use `is_array`

Answer (score 0):

According to the CodeIgniter support pages a directory name won't be listed as an array value, but as an array index.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html

Comment: `$map = directory_map('./uploads/'.$user_id.'/files', TRUE, FALSE);
print_r($map);`
this is my code which is returning above array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`is_dir()`**

**Example:**

```
<?php

// Your array
$files_and_dirs = array(
            'preview.zip',
            'RealEsta - Email Marketing Template.zip',
            'thumbnail',
            'thumbnail.jpg'
        );


// Now loop the above array
foreach($files_and_dirs as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_dir("abc/xyz/".$value))
    {
        unset($files_and_dirs[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it many ways(currently I can think 3 way).
 **way 1:**

```
$map = directory_map('./uploads/'.$user_id.'/files', 2, FALSE);//set second parameter as 2
foreach($map as $key=>$m)
{
    if(is_array($m))
    {
        unset($map[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($map);//now $map only contains files name
```

**way 2:**

```
$map = directory_map('./uploads/'.$user_id.'/files', 2, FALSE);//set second parameter as 2
foreach($map as $key=>$m)
{
    if(!is_int($key))
    {
        unset($map[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($map);
```

**way 3:**

```
$map = directory_map('./uploads/'.$user_id.'/files', 1, FALSE);//As you did
foreach($map as $key=>$m)
{
    if(is_dir('./uploads/'.$user_id.'/files'.$m))
    {
        unset($map[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($map);
```